# Help With finding Taylor Series to evaluate the sum $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(3n)!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, taylor-expansion

I have tried finding a Taylor series to evaluate the sum $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(3n)!}$, but am unable to find such a function. Is there a Taylor Series that could frame this sum?

Comment: Start with $e^x=\sum_n x^n/n!$ and Look at $g(x)=e^{x}+e^{wx}+e^{w^2x}$ for $w=e^{2\pi i/3}$. What happens with the terms with exponent not divisible by $3$?

Comment: @PeterForeman This is only useful given the magical knowledge of the closed-form for this power series.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Find a differential equation for
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{3n}}{(3n)!}
$$
Differentiate this 3 times and relate it to the original.

Comment: This is the most general/systematic way to tackle such questions, provided some familiarity with solving differential equations.

Comment: @ClementC. By what measure? That is just an empty claim. It is just one approach. That's all.

Comment: It's a very general approach which can be used for many things of the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$, while many other approaches don't. That's all.

Answer (score 3):

If one has a function given by a convergent power series
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+\cdots$$
then the sum of every third term
$$g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{3n}x^{3n}=a_0+a_3x^3+a_6x^6+a_9x^9+\cdots$$
may be obtained by the trick of "series trisection".

Write $\newcommand{\om}{\omega}\om=\exp(2\pi i/3)=\frac12(-1+i\sqrt3)$,
so that $\om^3=1$, and $1+\om+\om^2=0$. Then
$$f(\om x)=a_0+\om a_1x+\om^2 a_2x^2+a_3x^3+\cdots$$
and
$$f(\om^2 x)=a_0+\om^2 a_1x+\om a_2x^2+a_3x^3+\cdots.$$
Adding these to each other, and to $f(x)$ gives
$$f(x)+f(\omega x)+f(\omega^2x)=3a_0+3a_3x^3+3a_6x^6+\cdots=3g(x).$$

In your application, you want to compute $g(1)$ where $f(x)=\exp(x)$.

Comment: This trick is also known as a root-of-unity filter, on the grounds that $1^n+\omega^n+\omega^{2n}=0$ if $n$ isn't a multiple of 3.